# Arranging Books on a Shelf

Tags: combinatorics

Robert wants to arrange the books for Statistics, Calculus, Geometry, Algebra, and Trigonometry on a shelf. In how many arrangements can he keep them on the shelf such that the Algebra and Trigonometry books are not together

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** How many different arrangements are possible, if there is no restriction?

**Hint 2** How many different ways can you arrange the books so that A and T are together?